# jQuery Mobile code that worked in document.ready() does not work in document.bind(pageinit, ..)

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using a Rails gem called Client Side Validations ([here](https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations/blob/3-2-stable/vendor/assets/javascripts/rails.validations.js)) that does exactly as its name suggests.
I noticed that it was only working the first time a page was loaded and not again, and then I realised that it was because of the whole ajax load thing not firing the ready() event. So I switched the relevant part of the library to use pageinit, and now nothing happens. I get the alert message, but the validations do not fire.

The code adjusted for jQM that no longer works.

```
  // $(document).bind('pageinit', function() {
  //   alert(1)
  //   ClientSideValidations.disableValidators();
  //   return $(ClientSideValidations.selectors.forms).validate();
  // });
```

The original "working" code.

```
 $(function() {
    alert(1)
    ClientSideValidations.disableValidators();
    return $(ClientSideValidations.selectors.forms).validate();
  });
```

I have not changed anything else other than this snippet of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the one below and see

```
$(document).on('pageshow', function() {
   alert(1)
   ClientSideValidations.disableValidators();
   return $(ClientSideValidations.selectors.forms).validate();
});
```

If you want it fired when the page loaded for the first time then use `pagecreate` or if you want it fired everytime you refresh the page then use `pageshow`

Ideally you can make it specific to a page like below. Lets assume page id is `testpage`

```
$(document).on('pageshow', '#testpage', function() {
   alert(1)
   ClientSideValidations.disableValidators();
   return $(ClientSideValidations.selectors.forms).validate();
});
```

If you insist of using `pageinit` then try as below

```
$( "#testpage" ).on( "pageinit", function( event ) {
  alert( "This page was just enhanced by jQuery Mobile!" );
});
```

[documentation is here](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pageinit/)

Comment: Thanks! Why was 'pageinit' not working? According to the docs it is a replacement for .ready()

Comment: as far as I know `pageinit` is used to set global config details such as loader's theme etc.

Comment: So you use 'pageshow' whenever you want a 'ready' event on jQM?

Comment: Since the way `ready` and `pageshow` works different, I can't say I use this instead of this. But I can say if I want and event to be fired everytime DOM loaded on the browser, then I'd use `pageshow`.

Answer (score 1):

When you are on pageInit the components of your webpage are not there yet so you cant set validations or try to find anything. It used mostly to set global configurations, variables and preconfigurations.

As stated by Mayu the right way to do it is using the on with pageshow.